# Providing an SSH based AJAX terminal on Django app

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssh, terminal, gateone

I am working on a Django app with following features.

- *online terminal* to all users on my local network
- The terminal frame should open at the *bottom view*, as soon as they
  are logged in.
- There's a code  *editor in the top frame*.

Their exists a linux account on the server with the same credentials that they use to login.

What I want:

- spawn a terminal instance
- ssh's to their remote account
- change directory to their home directory as directed by ssh-config file
- persist the terminal connection until they logout.

Bear in mind, this is all local, so accounts are all localplace, accessible.

I have created the top editor view, for now and it looks like this 
[image: and it looks like this]

The terminal picture shown below is from [CodingGround](http://www.studyterminal.in/courses.php)
[image]

How do I add this sort of terminal here? How do sites like [StudyTerminal](http://www.studyterminal.in/courses.php) do it? How can I implement this?

I have looked at implementations of **shellInaBox** and **GateOne** but they occupy full screen space and are their own server. I don't want another server just to provide a terminal. Can anybody help me sort this out?

Probably like a Jquery / AJAX terminal interface that takes the following parameters:

```
new terminal{

   ssh_location : 10.10.56.24,
   port: 12001,
   username: username,
   password: ######,
   window_height: 100px;
   window_width: 200px;
   resizable:none
}
```

What's very important is that the terminal session should not occupy the full screen. Heavy functionalities such as multi user sessions, security may or not be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is real necromancy, but I'm searching and answering all questions about Web Terminals.

You have two major options:

- [xterm.js](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/)
- [jQuery Terminal](https://terminal.jcubic.pl/)

The first will allow creating a real Linux terminal you can connect it to a real Unix TTY. With xterm.js you can create real SSH where you can even run an editor like vi.

Here is an article that shows how to create a terminal with xterm.js: [How to create web-based terminals](https://dev.to/saisandeepvaddi/how-to-create-web-based-terminals-38d)

The second option will allow you to create a Web Terminal where you can do your stuff in JavaScript. if you want to use Django and AJAX, you can also do that.

And here is an article on how to use jQuery Terminal: [How to create interactive terminal like website with JavaScript?](https://itnext.io/how-to-create-interactive-terminal-like-website-888bb0972288)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I evolved from an intern to a senior software engineer haha.  I'd ended up using Wetty/Paramiko for terminal/SFTP back in early 2017 https://github.com/isopropylcyanide/NIT-J-Code-Compiler/blob/master/editor/scripts/terminal.py